# How can I create a numpy array holding values of a multi-variable function?

Tags: python, function, multidimensional-array, numpy

I want to create an array holding a function `f(x,y,z)`.  If it were a function of one variable I'd do, for instance:

```
sinx = numpy.sin(numpy.linspace(-5,5,100))
```

to get `sin(x)` for `x` in `[-5,5]`

How can I do the same to get, for instance `sin(x+y+z)`?

Comment: What would be the values for x,y,z and/or how do you plan to generate them?

Comment: x,y,z would be the cartesian product of `numpy.linspace(-5,5,100)` over all three dimensions.  I don't know the best way to generate them.  I guess that's a pre-requisite for the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I seem to have found a way:

```
# define the range of x,y,z
x_range = numpy.linspace(x_min,x_max,x_num)
y_range = numpy.linspace(y_min,y_max,y_num)
z_range = numpy.linspace(z_min,z_max,z_num)

# create arrays x,y,z in the correct dimensions
# so that they create the grid
x,y,z = numpy.ix_(x_range,y_range,z_range)

# calculate the function of x, y and z
sinxyz = numpy.sin(x+y+z)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
xyz = numpy.mgrid[-5:5,-5:5,-5:5]
sinxyz = numpy.sin(xyz[0]+xyz[1]+xyz[2])
```

Answer (score -1):

The numpy.mgrid function would work equally well:

```
x,y,z = numpy.mgrid[x_min:x_max:x_num, y_min:y_max:y_num, z_min:z_max:z_num]  
sinxyz = numpy.sin(x+y+z)
```

edit: to get it to work `x_num`, `y_num` and `z_num` have to be explicit numbers followed by `j`, e.g., `x,y = numpy.mgrid[-1:1:10j, -1:1:10j]`